# What is gulp.src for?

Tags: javascript, gulp

Im trying to use [gulp prompt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-prompt):

```
gulp.src('test.js')
    .pipe(prompt.prompt({
        type: 'input',
        name: 'task',
        message: 'Which task would you like to run?'
    }, function(res){
        //value is in res.task (the name option gives the key) 
 }));
```

Im confused to actually what gulp.src is for? I don't have a src I just want to prompt the user for an input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gulp.src` creates the stream of source files to perform the 'piped' operations on. In your example you're asking for a task to perform, which means you're asking what task to perform on the file `test.js`.

If you want to ask what task to perform, and then run one or more gulp tasks I think you'll need to write a plain old nodejs application that asks for the input and then start the `gulp [name of task]` from there.

Comment: Thanks, the code was just an example from gulp prompt. What if I don;t want to create a stream of source files and just run the prompt?

Comment: That's not what gulp is for. If you just want a prompt and do something that is not file related (what gulp is for) you should probably just use nodejs and call your prompt script from there